# pd.DataFrame(list of dicts) showing NaN's for a clean input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I print my dict:

```
males_arrs_dict = []
for i in range (1, len(rows1)):
    males_arrs_dict.append({cols[0]: str(rows1[i][0]).replace(",","")})
    males_arrs_dict.append({cols[1]: str(rows1[i][1]).replace(",","")})
    males_arrs_dict.append({cols[2]: str(rows1[i][2]).replace(",","")})
    males_arrs_dict.append({cols[3]: str(rows1[i][3]).replace(",","")})

print(males_arrs_dict)
```

It looks okay

```
[{'age': '2'}, {'sedentary': '1000'}, {'moderately_active': '1000'}, {'active': '1000'}, {'age': '3'}, {'sedentary': '1000'}, {'moderately_active': '1400'}, {'active': '1400'}, {'age': '4'}, {'sedentary': '1200'}, {'moderately_active': '1400'}, {'active': '1600'}, {'age': '5'}, {'sedentary': '1200'}, {'moderately_active': '1400'}, {'active': '1600'}, {'age': '6'}, {'sedentary': '1400'}, {'moderately_active': '1600'}, {'active': '1800'}, {'age': '7'}, {'sedentary': '1400'}, {'moderately_active': '1600'}, {'active': '1800'}, {'age': '8'}, {'sedentary': '1400'}, {'moderately_active': '1600'}, {'active': '2000'}, {'age': '9'}, {'sedentary': '1600'}, {'moderately_active': '1800'}, {'active': '2000'}, {'age': '10'}, {'sedentary': '1600'}, {'moderately_active': '1800'}, {'active': '2200'}, {'age': '11'}, {'sedentary': '1800'}, {'moderately_active': '2000'}, {'active': '2200'}, {'age': '12'}, {'sedentary': '1800'}, {'moderately_active': '2200'}, {'active': '2400'}, {'age': '13'}, {'sedentary': '2000'}, {'moderately_active': '2200'}, {'active': '2600'}, {'age': '14'}, {'sedentary': '2000'}, {'moderately_active': '2400'}, {'active': '2800'}, {'age': '15'}, {'sedentary': '2200'}, {'moderately_active': '2600'}, {'active': '3000'}, {'age': '16'}, {'sedentary': '2400'}, {'moderately_active': '2800'}, {'active': '3200'}, {'age': '17'}, {'sedentary': '2400'}, {'moderately_active': '2800'}, {'active': '3200'}, {'age': '18'}, {'sedentary': '2400'}, {'moderately_active': '2800'}, {'active': '3200'}, {'age': '19-20'}, {'sedentary': '2600'}, {'moderately_active': '2800'}, {'active': '3000'}, {'age': '21-25'}, {'sedentary': '2400'}, {'moderately_active': '2800'}, {'active': '3000'}, {'age': '26-30'}, {'sedentary': '2400'}, {'moderately_active': '2600'}, {'active': '3000'}, {'age': '31-35'}, {'sedentary': '2400'}, {'moderately_active': '2600'}, {'active': '3000'}, {'age': '36-40'}, {'sedentary': '2400'}, {'moderately_active': '2600'}, {'active': '2800'}, {'age': '41-45'}, {'sedentary': '2200'}, {'moderately_active': '2600'}, {'active': '2800'}, {'age': '46-50'}, {'sedentary': '2200'}, {'moderately_active': '2400'}, {'active': '2800'}, {'age': '51-55'}, {'sedentary': '2200'}, {'moderately_active': '2400'}, {'active': '2800'}, {'age': '56-60'}, {'sedentary': '2200'}, {'moderately_active': '2400'}, {'active': '2600'}, {'age': '61-65'}, {'sedentary': '2000'}, {'moderately_active': '2400'}, {'active': '2600'}, {'age': '66-70'}, {'sedentary': '2000'}, {'moderately_active': '2200'}, {'active': '2600'}, {'age': '71-75'}, {'sedentary': '2000'}, {'moderately_active': '2200'}, {'active': '2600'}, {'age': '76\xa0and up'}, {'sedentary': '2000'}, {'moderately_active': '2200'}, {'active': '2400'}]
```

But the dataframe shows many NaN's

```
males_df = pd.DataFrame(males_arrs_dict)#.astype(str)
males_df
```

[imgmine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF8YY.png)

I tried

```
m_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(males_arrs_dict)

ma_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(males_arrs_dict)
```

with the same results.

I also tried

```
males_df = pd.DataFrame(males_arrs_dict).astype(str)
```

but it didn't help.

Why is this happening?

Comment: pandas expects a dictionary per row, containing all keys and values for that row.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael was correct.

This worked:

```
males_dict = []
for i in range (1, len(rows1)):
    males_dict.append({cols[0]: rows1[i][0],
                            cols[1]: rows1[i][1],
                            cols[2]: rows1[i][2],
                            cols[3]: rows1[i][3]})

test_df = pd.DataFrame(males_dict)

test_df
```

output:

[correctOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR43T.png)

Answer (score 0):

Each element of the array is mapped to a row in the data frame, and the attribute names are mapped to columns. So, since each element of your array has only one attribute, and different in all cases, you get a DataFrame with a lot of columns that not all elements have, and then the DataFrame is filled with NaNs.

For example, the first element `{'age': '2'}` does not have the `sedentary`, `moderately_active`, or `active` properties. So the first row is going to receive `NaN` in all those columns except `age`.